# for loop on apps script running very slow, how can i make it run faster?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that I have been using for 2 years and it was working perfectly until recently. It started to give a timeout warning a couple of weeks ago and now it's not really running anymore.
The code pulls every picture from 13 different folders on google drive and then adds them to a sheet, it was giving the timeout warning after row 200. I modified it a bit but i'm still getting the exceeded maximum execution time warning (after 360 rows now)

I would really appreciate it if somebody had a solution for this. The script used to run pretty fast (around 2-3 rows per second) and now it's taking around 3-4secs per row.
Thank you so much in advance!

Here's the script:

```
function Iteration() {
  var lista_carpetas = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("carpetas").getRange("A2:A").getValues(); //event list
  var lista_carpetas_ok = lista_carpetas.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    if (e[0]) ar.push(e[0])
    return ar;
  }, []); 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("data");
  sheet.clear()
  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Size", "URL", "Download", "Description", "Image","Folder Id"]);

  for (var i = 5; i <8; i++) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("data");
    var folderId = lista_carpetas_ok[i];
    var season1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("carpetas").getRange("B2:B").getValues(); //event list
  var season = season1.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    if (e[0]) ar.push(e[0])
    return ar;
  }, []);

 
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    var contents = folder.getFiles();

    var cnt = 0;
    var file;

    while (contents.hasNext()) {
        var file = contents.next();
        cnt++;

        Logger.log(file);
        Logger.log(cnt);
// writes the various chunks to the spreadsheet- just delete anything you don't want
            data = [
                file.getName(),
                file.getDateCreated(),
                file.getSize(),
                file.getUrl(),
                "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + file.getId(),
                file.getDescription(),
                "=image(\"https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId() +"\")",
                folderId,
            ];

            sheet.appendRow(data);
    };

  }
  
}
```

Comment: if your code works there is the codereview SE that might be a better place for this sort of question

Comment: to start you can move the methods which will do the same thing during each iteration outside the loop to avoid creating lots of network traffic on each iteration. For example, move `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetName("data")` outside the for loop

Comment: I think that in your script, there are several modification points for reducing process cost. But, about `The code pulls every picture from 13 different folders on google drive`, when I saw your script, from `for (var i = 5; i <8; i++) {}`, the files are retrieved from only 3 folders. So I cannot understand your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation and your goal?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my mistake. I didn't copy the whole code because the rest is just 4 more loops just like the one that i copied but for the other folders. So 4 loops in total pull the pictures from 13 different folders on google drive, and each loop pulls the pictures from 3-4 folders.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand `So 4 loops in total pull the pictures from 13 different folders on google drive, and each loop pulls the pictures from 3-4 folders.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your actual question?

Comment: Hi! don't apologize. We have 13 folders on google drive which hold pictures from 2019-2022, and I made a loop that pulls the pictures from each folder that holds pictures for that year. Therefore the script has 4 for loops (only showing the first one above, which pulls the pictures from folders in rows 6 to 8, which are the folders for year 2018) that pull pictures from the folders on google drive. Did I explain it better now?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed your reply just now. I apologize for this. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your explanations in your reply,

> I didn't copy the whole code because the rest is just 4 more loops just like the one that i copied but for the other folders. So 4 loops in total pull the pictures from 13 different folders on google drive, and each loop pulls the pictures from 3-4 folders.

> We have 13 folders on google drive which hold pictures from 2019-2022, and I made a loop that pulls the pictures from each folder that holds pictures for that year. Therefore the script has 4 for loops (only showing the first one above, which pulls the pictures from folders in rows 6 to 8, which are the folders for year 2018) that pull pictures from the folders on google drive.

I believe your current situation and your goal are as follows.

- You have 13 folder IDs in the column "A" of "carpetas" sheet.
- In your script, you want to use the values from "A6:A8" of "carpetas" sheet.
- By retrieving the file metadata from the folders of folder IDs retrieved from "A7:A9" of "carpetas" sheet, you want to put the retrieved file metadata to "data" sheet.
- You want to reduce the process cost of the script.

#### Modification points:

- When you want to retrieve the folder IDs from the cells "A6:A8", when I saw your script, it seems that your script retrieves the values from the cells "A7:A9".
- In your script, `appendRow` is used in the loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("data")` can be put out of the loop.
- `season` is not used. So `var season1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("carpetas").getRange("B2:B").getValues()` can be removed.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function Iteration() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var carpetasSheet = ss.getSheetByName("carpetas");
  var lista_carpetas = carpetasSheet.getRange("A2:A" + carpetasSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var lista_carpetas_ok = lista_carpetas.filter(([a]) => a);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data");
  sheet.clear();
  var files = [["Name", "Date", "Size", "URL", "Download", "Description", "Image", "Folder Id"]];
  for (var i = 4; i < 7; i++) {
    console.log(lista_carpetas_ok[i][0]) // Here, you can see the folder ID in the log.
    var folderId = lista_carpetas_ok[i][0];
    try {
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
      var contents = folder.getFiles();
      while (contents.hasNext()) {
        var file = contents.next();
        var id = file.getId();
        data = [
          file.getName(),
          file.getDateCreated(),
          file.getSize(),
          file.getUrl(),
          "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + id,
          file.getDescription(),
          "=image(\"https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + id + "\")",
          folderId,
        ];
        files.push(data);
      };
    } catch (e) {
      // In this modification, when your folder ID cannot be used, that folder ID is skipped. At that time, an error message can be seen in the log.
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  }
  if (files.length == 0) return;
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, files.length, files[0].length).setValues(files);
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script retrieves the folder IDs from the cells "A6:A8" because of your reply of `only showing the first one above, which pulls the pictures from folders in rows 6 to 8, which are the folders for year 2018`. But if you want to retrieved the folder IDs from "A7:A9", please modify `for (var i = 4; i < 7; i++) {` to `for (var i = 5; i < 8; i++) {`.

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: it works perfectly and it's really fast!!! thank you so much, you saved me!

Comment: @Vivian Roberts Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Iteration() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("carpetas");
  const evlist = sh0.getRange("A6:A9").getValues().flat();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("data");
  sh1.clear();
  sh1.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Size", "URL", "Download", "Description", "Image", "Folder Id"]);
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(evlist[i]);
    let contents = folder.getFiles();
    while (contents.hasNext()) {
      let file = contents.next();
      sh1.appendRow([file.getName(),file.getDateCreated(),file.getSize(),file.getUrl(),"https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + file.getId(),file.getDescription(),"=image(\"https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId() + "\")",evlist[i]]);
    };
  }
}
```

- If you must use ranges like "A2:A" then always use the form "A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow() otherwise you always have to remove the nulls inserted in the range from getLastRow() to getMaxRows() which is a big waste of time.  In this case just using a fixed range actually works better since you're only using three rows.
- You could be storing all of your image in Google Image Library and removing this with their API.